# How do you order a list by numbers then by strings descending?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of data that I would like to order descending but i would like to start out with numbers then go to strings. 
Example of what I'm looking for.

```
43a
34a
22a
11d
ztc
xtc
ytc
```

but if you just do

```
SELECT list FROM table ORDER BY list DESC;
```

It outputs the list like this.

```
ztc
xtc
ytc
43a
34a
22a
11d
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what about values like `z34` or `4z3` ?

Comment: 43a 4z3
34a
22a
11d z34
ztc
xtc
ytc

Comment: If it starts with a number I would like it at the top of the list if it starts with a string i would like it at the bottom of the list or there about.

Comment: You can try my answer which cover the `43a 4z3` case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test table**

```
CREATE TABLE Data (str varchar(3))

INSERT INTO Data
SELECT '43a' UNION
SELECT '34a' UNION
SELECT '22a' UNION
SELECT '11d' UNION
SELECT 'ztc' UNION
SELECT 'xtc' UNION
SELECT 'ytc'
```

**TSQL**

```
SELECT str FROM DATA
ORDER BY 1-ISNUMERIC(LEFT(str, 1)) , str DESC
```

[ISNUMERIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) return 1 for a number, 0 for non-number, so if u sort by `1-ISNUMERIC` first - numbers appear first. After that you can sort by field DESC

**Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e92a08/6**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT A FROM (VALUES('ztc'), ('xtc'), ('ytc'),('43a'),('34a'),('22a'),('11d')) T(A)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY Left(A, PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', A) - 1) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into two queries a temporary table.

```
DECLARE @TempList AS TABLE(
     listItem AS varchar(max)
)
```

In the first query, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO @TempList (listItem)
SELECT list 
FROM table 
Where ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(list), 1, 1))
ORDER BY list DESC;
```

What this will do is select all entries that  start with a number and add them to the list in descending  order.

Then, you just remove the 'NOT' from the WHERE statement the letters:

```
Insert into @TempList
SELECT list 
FROM table 
Where Not ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(list), 1, 1))
ORDER BY list DESC;
```

Finally, to get the full list you just use:

```
SELECT listItem FROM @TempList
```